# Derivative of inverse of matrix wrt itself in Einstein notation

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, tensors, index-notation

I'm struggling to work with Einstein notation to derive $\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA}$.

I.e. I understand given $A^{-1}A=I$ I can differentiate both sides to  get $\frac{d}{dA}A^{-1}A=0$ and apply product rule then rearrange to get $\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA} = -A^{-2}$.

The problem is deriving this in Einstein notation.  My indices end up all over the place. I.e.

$\frac{d}{dA_{ij}}(A^{-1}_{kl}A_{lm}) = (\frac{d}{dA_{ij}}A^{-1}_{kl})A_{lm} + A^{-1}_{kl}(\frac{d}{dA_{ij}}A_{lm})= (\frac{d}{dA_{ij}}A^{-1}_{kl})A_{lm} + A^{-1}_{kl}(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm})$

$\iff \frac{d}{dA_{ij}}A^{-1}_{kl} = -A^{-1}_{ki}\delta_{jm}A^{-1}_{lm} = -A^{-1}_{ki}A^{-1}_{lj}$

... a fourth-order tensor?!  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, any hints much appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Derivative_of_the_inverse_of_a_second-order_tensor) says I'm nearly correct (one of my indices seems the wrong way around), but I've seen the matrix (i.e. 2nd order) version in various places too.  Very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix $n$ by $n$ matrix.  Then the derivative of the inverse function at $A$ is by definition a linear map $L_A\colon M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that for all   $n$ by $n$ matrices $D$:

$$\frac{(A+\delta D)^{-1}-A^{-1}}{\delta}\to L_A (D),$$
as the real valued variable $\delta\to0$.

For any $D$ and $\delta$ sufficiently small (with respect to moduli of the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}D$), we have the following sum converging:
$$\Sigma= 1-A^{-1}D\delta+(A^{-1}D\delta)^2-(A^{-1}D\delta)^3+\cdots
$$

Then: $$\Sigma A^{-1}(A+\delta D)=\Sigma(1+A^{-1}D\delta)=I_n$$

Thus $\Sigma A^{-1}=(A+\delta D)^{-1}$ and
$$\frac{(A+\delta D)^{-1}-A^{-1}}{\delta}=\frac{\Sigma A^{-1}-A^{-1}}{\delta}=\frac{\Sigma-1}\delta A^{-1}$$
$$
=-A^{-1}DA^{-1}+(A^{-1}D)^2A^{-1}\delta+\cdots\to -A^{-1}DA^{-1},
$$
as $\delta \to 0$.

Thus $L_A(D)=-A^{-1}DA^{-1}$.  Note that $L_A$ has to be a rank four tensor, as it denotes a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes \mathbb{R}^n$ to itself.

As for the order of the indices, let $(L_A)_{ij,kl}$ deonte the coefficient in the $ij$'th entry of $L_A(D)$, where $D$ has a $1$ in the $kl$'th entry and $0$'s elsewhere.  Then we have:$$
(L_A)_{ij,kl}=-(A^{-1})_{ik}(A^{-1})_{lj}
$$

That is the $l$'th column of $A^{-1}D$ is the $k$'th column of $A^{-1}$, with the remaining entries of $A^{-1}D$ all $0$.  Thus to get the entries in the $i$'th row of $-A^{-1}DA^{-1}$, you must multiply $-(A^{-1})_{ik}$ by the entries in the $l$'th row of $A^{-1}$.  That is: $$(-A^{-1}DA^{-1})_{ij}=-(A^{-1})_{ik}(A^{-1})_{lj},$$
as required.

---

Here is a derivation of the expression for $L_A(D)$ which is more similar to your argument.  Note this argument assumes $L_A$ exists, and just works out what it is.

Suppose some linear map $L_A$ exists such that $L_A(D)$ is the required limit (top equation).  The derivative of the identity function is just the identity linear map $I_A\colon D \mapsto D$.  There is a bilinear map on linear maps, sending $(A,B)\mapsto AB$.

If we take the tensor product of the inverse maps and identity, and compose with multiplication, we get the constant function sending $A\mapsto I_n$, with derivative $0_n$.

Thus by the product rule:$$
0_n=A^{-1}I_A(D)+L_A(D)A =A^{-1}D+L_A(D)A.\qquad (1)
$$
Rearranging: $$L_A(D)=-A^{-1}DA^{-1},$$ as before.

Now let's write this in your notation and see where you went wrong:
$$
0=A^{-1}+\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA}A
$$
The point is that here the $A^{-1}$ denotes left multiplication by $A^{-1}$ (if you compare with my equation $(1)$).  It would be better to write
$$
0=(A^{-1})_L+\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA}A
$$

Thus if you compose with right multiplication by $A^{-1}$ you get:
$$
0=(A^{-1})_L(A^{-1})_R+\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA}
$$
so
$$
\frac{dA^{-1}}{dA}=-(A^{-1})_L(A^{-1})_R
$$
The moral of the story is that when multiplication by $A^{-1}$ can mean more than one thing, it is a good idea to use notation which keeps track of exactly what it means.

Comment: This looks like a derivation via directional derivative?  I.e. $D(A^{-1})[D] = -A^{-1}DA^{-1}$.  But then if $D=I=\delta_{kl}$ we recover the second order version?  

To be honest, I struggle to understand the "we have the following sum converging" bit and the following lines involving $\Sigma$, I've not seen that before.

Comment: Yes it expresses the directional derivative.  Also yes in a certain direction this linear map coincides with another linear map (namely left multiplication by $-A^{-2}$), but in general it is not the same linear map.  For the convergence I am just saying that if you take any matrix, and multiply it by a small enough scalar, then its powers will tend to $0$, so we can use the usual identity for geometric sums $$(1+a)(1-a+a^2-a^3+\cdots)=1,$$ as long as $a^n\to 0$.  Your method of calculation should also give the correct answer, if you are careful - I will add this in an edit when I have time.

Comment: If you want to have a go at fixing your answer before I get round to it - the key is to think of matrices as vectors, and matrix multiplication as a bilinear map, and note that differentiation respects Leibniz' rule with respect to this bilinear map.

Comment: Also, for the indices, it would have been cleaner, but less explicit  if I just said $$(A^{-1}DA^{-1})_{ij}=(A^{-1})_{ik}D_{kl}(A^{-1})_{lj}=(A^{-1})_{ik}(A^{-1})_{lj}D_{kl},$$ so $$(L_A) _{ij,kl}=(A^{-1})_{ik}(A^{-1})_{lj}.$$

Comment: @Dave I have added a derivation using the product rule, similar to yours, and explained why your calculation went wrong, essentially because your notation was not sufficiently detailed to keep track of what was going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yeah I can see where I got confused with the multiplication of the inverse now.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in fact supposed to be a fourth-order tensor. When you differentiate a rank-$r$ tensor with respect to a rank-$s$ tensor, you get a rank-$(r+s-2k)$ tensor if you contract $k$ pairs away, but by default $k=0$.

If this surprises you, consider a result for vectors, $\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial V_j}=\delta_{ij}$. In the problem at hand, we get a "square matrix" from the vector space in which $A,\,A^{-1}$ live as vectors to itself; but relative to the space $A$ acts on, the number of indices is $2^2=4$.

Your calculation strategy shows$$0=\frac{\partial\delta_{km}}{\partial A_{ij}}=\frac{\partial A^{-1}_{kl}}{\partial A_{ij}}A_{lm}+A^{-1}_{kl}\color{blue}{\frac{\partial A_{lm}}{\partial A_{ij}}}.$$The blue derivative depends on the degrees of freedom, e.g. it shouldn't just be a product of two Kronecker deltas if $A$ varies within the symmetric matrices. So let's not evaluate it yet. What matters is$$\frac{\partial A_{kn}^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}}=\frac{\partial A_{kl}^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}}A_{lm}A^{-1}_{mn}=-A^{-1}_{kl}\frac{\partial A_{lm}}{\partial A_{ij}}A^{-1}_{mn}.$$Finally, if $A$ is arbitrary, you correctly deduce$$\frac{\partial A_{lm}}{\partial A_{ij}}=\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}\implies\frac{\partial A_{kn}^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}}=-A^{-1}_{ki}A^{-1}_{jn}.$$Or in matrix notation, infinitesimal variations satisfy $dA^{-1}=-A^{-1}dA\cdot A^{-1}$, which in the $1\times1$ case reduces to the usual $dx^{-1}=-x^{-2}dx$. Notice that if $\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}$ were some rank-$2$ matrix $M$, that would imply $dA^{-1}=MdA$, which isn't the most general possible linear relationship between infinitesimal matrices $dA,\,dA^{-1}$, because square matrices live in a space whose dimension is the square of that of the original vectors.

Comment: This really helps, thanks for sticking with indicial notation.  I'm curious about the comment "it shouldn't just be a product of two Kronecker deltas if A varies within the symmetric matrices".  I'm wondering if that could explain where I've seen the matrix form of this equation as $dA^{-1}/dA = -A^{-2}$, which is clearly rank 2 - would this be correct if A was symmetric, somehow?

Comment: @Dave $dA^{-1}=-A^{-1}dA\cdot A^{-1}$ can only be simplified to $dA^{-1}=-A^{-2}dA$ if $dA$ commutes with $A^{-1}$, I'd be curious to know what assumptions are made in the source where you saw that version. I don't think it's related to the symmetry issue. If $A,\,dA$ are symmetric,$$\frac{\partial A_{lm}}{\partial A_{ij}}=\frac12\left(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}+\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}\right)$$(it can't simply be $\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}$, as that's not $l\leftrightarrow m$-symmetric). You may want to ponder another important special case, where $A,\,dA$ are antisymmetric.

Comment: @J.G. can you please explain more "you get a rank-(+−2) tensor if you contract  pairs away, but by default =0". In what circumstances is k>0? Do you have a reference that is helpful?

Comment: @joshlk Here's an example. Let $X_{ijkl}:=\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{kl}}$. Then $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{il}}=X_{ijil}$ contracts viz. $k=1$, so transforms as a rank-$2$ tensor, which you might denote e.g. as $Y_{jl}$.

Comment: @J.G. when would such a tensor derivative arise? Can you provide an example?